# Unable to commit or push updates to master after adding them

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am having trouble pushing updates from my local repository to my GitHub master.

I have cloned a test repository that I initially created on GitHub, have made a few small updates, and am now trying to push these updates back to the master.

After adding the files, I am getting errors for both commit and push which appear to be circular and I'm unclear on how to resolve.

I have added the updates from my local repository using:

```
git add .
```

When I try to commit I get the following message:

```
git commit -m "Test update of Index.html"`

On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)`
```

When I then try to push the updates I get the following error:

```
git push origin master  

error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Username/HelloWorld.git' `
```

The troubleshooting advice I can find for this error all say to first commit my updates, which I am unable to do.

Comment: `git push origin master` - but you're on `main`... In general, you should just be able to `git push`, specifying the remote and branch is only necessary when you're not doing the default thing of pushing to the remote named `origin` and the branch matching your local one.

Comment: Please read: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `git add` and `git commit` calls seem to be successful. Your `git push origin master` call fails because there's not branch `master` in the remote repository. Since your local branch is `main`, I'm guessing you meant to push to the remote branch of the same name. You could use `git push origin main`, or even just `git push`, and rely on the defaults.